# Datetime result by mapreduce of pymongo off by one day

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I stored some data in `mongodb`, where there are some `datetime` data like:
`ISODate("2015-08-25T00:00:00.000+0000")`

After using `mapreduce` function from python, I emit the datetime data as key, but the result turns to be like:

```
"_id" : ISODate("2015-08-26T00:00:00.000+0000")
```

which is just off by one day from the original data.

How can I solve this question? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code you've written?

Comment: yes, the map function is as follows: 
`code`    mapper = Code("""
        function() {
           var key = this.rtime;
           key.setHours(8);
           key.setMinutes(0);
           key.setSeconds(0);
           key.setMilliseconds(0);
           var value = {
                         ......
                       };
           emit(key, value);
        };
    """)
`code`

Comment: the reason why I set hours to 8 is that because I am at GMT+8. to set it to 8 can get a datetime with time at 00:00

Comment: @Pio , can you help?

Comment: Can you update your question with a few entries from your data set, the query you're executing and what you expect your result will be? (use edit button below the tags, don't add it as a comment).

Comment: I have a lot of data searched on different days. I use mapreduce function to calculate maximum minimum and average value for different days, so I emit date as key and prices as value. Then I found the date in the result is off by one day on Aug 31, but today I found it right.... Nothing did I do.